# CcAvenue integration with angular js

Tags: angularjs, ccavenue

I have received the merchant id  test api key from Ccavenue i just want to know how i can integrate Ccavenue with angular Js website. Screens required

Comment: Did you go through in making the payment code successful in angular?

Answer (score 3):

For Angular 2+, You may check this article https://medium.com/@daveinside/integrating-ccavenue-in-node-js-angular-5-b9de44091062

I wrote this answer as there is a lack of help for Angular 2+ based CCAvenue Integration. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

1) **You can use non-seamless integration from integration kit(ccavenue provides it for different framework line)**

2) **At server create "encRequest" (encrypted form values using working key) and send to client along with accessCode**

3) **In your angular controller call your API which will return encRequest and accessCode**

4) **Once you get encRequest and accessCode follow following code**

```
 app.controller("changeProfileController", function($scope, $http, $sce){
     $scope.myText = ""; // ng-model for html response container in view

     $scope.ProfileData = {
        //custom and required data fields
     };
     $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/requestPaymentAPI',
        processData: false,
        data: JSON.stringify($scope.ProfileData)
     }).then(function(res){
        $scope.myText = $sce.trustAsHtml('<form id="nonseamless" method="post" name="redirect" action="https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction"  ><input type="text" name="access_code" id="access_code" value="'+ res.data.accessCode.trim() +'" style="display:none;" ><input type="text" id="encRequest" name="encRequest" value="'+ res.data.encRequest.trim() +'" style="display:none;" ><script language="javascript">document.redirect.submit();</script></form>');
      },function errorCallback(err){
          console.log(err);
      });     
});
```

5) **In your view add div in which you can render the html**

```
<div class="ccavenueResponse">{{ myText }}</div>
```

6) **It will redirect you to payment gateway form and after processing transaction it will return response string which you can process(decrypt the encrypted data of ccavenue response) at server side and display that data using URL based routes of that data**