# Cc avenue in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ccavenue

I seen a post here 
[CcAvenue integration with angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626353/ccavenue-integration-with-angular-js)

I'm not understanding which kit should be used in Angularjs.Please help me in integrating ccavenue in my angularjs project(mobile).

Thank You

Comment: There are no kits in AngularJS for this. what he has said is that you need to use some `kit` (`jar` in java or using `pip` for python) to configure the sever to handle request. From angularJS, you have what you need as the code has been shared .

Comment: Posting like that giving me error as Refused to apply style from 'https://www.ccavenue.com/mer_register/settings/css/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: And also with some modifications getting error Error Code: 10001 Invalid Request - Encrypted request invalid/not present. even thought sending correct format.